# 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) for ajax request with django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, http

I have the following Class Based View

```
class SupportView(BaseDetailView):

    def render_to_response(self):
       if self.request.method == "POST":
            message = "YES"
       else:
            message = "NO"
       return HttpResponse(message)
```

And following Jquery code:

```
    <script>
var username = $('.username').attr('data-username');
$('.destek').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/profiles/support/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"username":username, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
        dataType:"json"
    })
})
</script>
```

And following url

```
   url(r'^support/$', SupportView.as_view())
```

But when I click the button i see `127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/support/ 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) error. Any ideas ?`

Comment: Why are you using `BaseDetailView` Class? why are you overwriten the `render_to_resonse` ? Like @btoueg said, you must write the `post` method, but you can use CreateView, UpdateView, or FormView. What are you trying for?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to implement the `post` method in your view:

```
class SupportView(BaseDetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Since you didn't define the `post` method, it's the right behavior to get a `405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) error`.

Comment: Just for info: I had problem with localization: probably ajax request to /ajaxurl/ made a redirect to /en/ajaxurl/ (and this redirect was GET instead of the original POST)